# Google App Script SitesApp returning an empty array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I tried all methods available in the Google Sites API, examples

```
var site = SitesApp.getSite("example.com", "mysite");
```

the above method returns an empty array.

And the bellow method returns an error with "Invalid argument: url "

```
var site = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl("https://sites.google.com/domain/testweb");
```

How to read a Google Site properly using Google App Script ?

Details:

I own the site and the site is a new Google site NOT a classic one.

Comment: Is the site owned by you?

Comment: Yes. I'm the owner of the site. I have tried this scenario in my personal account. As well as I tried from GSuite Education account as well (As the amin) . No any difference.

Comment: Is the site new one or the classic one?

Comment: I tried a new site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites),

> A [rebuilt version of Sites](https://blog.google/products/g-suite/totally-rebuilt-sites-customer-tested/) was launched on November 22, 2016. Apps Script cannot currently access or modify Sites made with this version, but script can still access [classic Sites](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2016/11/a-totally-rebuilt-google-sitesnow.html).

So, you cannot access new sites with apps script.

Users who want to access new sites through apps script can  add a star(★ on top left) to this [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119709990) to let Google know you're interested and for Google to prioritize the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried the classic sites as well. The API is working but the In my GSuite Education account, its not comes with proper SSL. In my personal account, its fine. Please check this

https://sites.google.com/a/sci.pdn.ac.lk/batch10/

Comment: Thank you. I have added a new question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63647201/no-ssl-in-gsuite-education-classic-sites

Comment: @LahiruJ If you create a site manually, Is there ssl?

Comment: I created the site manually not automatically. No SSL there

Comment: @LahiruJ If so, that question should be directed to google support. Not here, as it has nothing to do with programming.